# Ajax loading iframe without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax, iframe

Using ajax I'm loading `iframes` and at given intervals it should change. Iframes are changing after specified intervals, but the page is refreshing.

How we can stop that?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a similar task recently. You should only have to modify the `src` attribute of the iframe and it should change.